# Bajaj pulsar RS200 shuts off while trying to slow down or stop the vehicle

Tags: engine, fuel-system, fuel-injection, pulsar, direct-bikes

I have been a owner of pulsar RS200;
ODO- 24,650,
idling RPM-1.5,
never touched FI system for servicing,
just gone a round trip of about 400kms, by start of the ride filled tank, while returning while it was having one line of fuel in the meter after deaccelerating to slow down, bike suddenly shut down and was not starting until i turned off and then turned on the kill switch, this kept repeating ever since every time when i try to slow down my bike or try to stop on a signal, what is the root cause for this issue, can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the owner's manual, when does it recommend spark plug replacement. Was the air filter cleaned or replaced? Throttle cleaned?